# File pathing issue with gulp and scripts

Tags: angularjs, gulp

So I have successfully setup my gulpfile.js to handle copying files to a  'dist' folder to then move over to my windows server, but am curious on how I can deal with file pathing? So my gulp looks like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');  
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
// var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
// var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');
var bases = {
    app: 'app/',
    dist: 'dist/',
};
var paths = {
    scripts: ['ppt/scripts/**/*.js'],
    styles: ['ppt/styles/**/*.css'],
    html: ['ppt/views/**/*.html'],
    assets: ['ppt/assets/**/*.png', 'ppt/assets/**/*.svg'],
    extras: ['index.html', '404.html', 'robots.txt', 'favicon.ico'],
};

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('bower', function() {
    // mainBowerFiles is used as a src for the task,
    // usually you pipe stuff through a task
    return gulp.src(mainBowerFiles())
        // Then pipe it to wanted directory, I use
        // dist/lib but it could be anything really
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/lib'))
});

// Delete the dist directory
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src(bases.dist).pipe(clean());
});
// Process scripts and concatenate them into one output file
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.src(paths.scripts, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(uglify()).pipe(concat('app.min.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'scripts/'));
});
// Imagemin images and ouput them in dist
// gulp.task('imagemin', ['clean'], function() {
//     gulp.src(paths.images, {
//         cwd: bases.app
//     }).pipe(imagemin()).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'assets/'));
// });
// Copy all other files to dist directly
gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function() {
    // Copy html
    gulp.src(paths.html, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'views'));
    // Copy styles
    gulp.src(paths.styles, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'styles'));
    //Copy assets
    gulp.src(paths.assets, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'assets'));
    // Copy app scripts
    gulp.src(paths.scripts, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist + 'scripts'));
    // Copy extra html5bp files
    gulp.src(paths.extras, {
        cwd: bases.app
    }).pipe(gulp.dest(bases.dist));
});
// A development task to run anytime a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*', ['scripts', 'copy']);
});
// Define the default task as a sequence of the above tasks
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'scripts', 'copy']);
```

In using angular mvc, my index.html which sets my pathing for scripts, 3rd party components, etc... looks like (not complete file, just lines that are applicable):

```
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../bower_components/kendo-ui/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="ppt/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- 3rd party libraries managed by Bower -->

<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/ng-file-upload-shim/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
<script src="../bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/checklist-model/checklist-model.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-validation-match/dist/angular-validation-match.js"></script>


<!-- Load app main script -->
<script src="ppt/scripts/app.js"></script>

<!-- Load services -->
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/authInterceptorService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/authService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/pptService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/claimsService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/swipesService.js"></script>    
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/recurService.js"></script>        
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/tokensManagerService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/docsService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/ordersService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/errorService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/utilsService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/cardsService.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/services/mobileAppService.js"></script>

<!-- Load controllers -->
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/indexController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/infoController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/pptController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/pptProfileController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/signupController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/logreg/forgotController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/claims/claimsController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/claims/swipeController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/claims/recurController.js"></script>    
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/docs/docsController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/orders/ordersController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/orders/orderController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/refreshController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/tokensManagerController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/associateController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/cards/cardsController.js"></script>
<script src="ppt/scripts/controllers/mobileapp/mobileAppController.js"></script>
<!-- Load custom filters -->
<!-- Load custom directives -->
```

This shown and said, what is the best way to understand setting the pathing so it works when in the 'dest' folder'? I try to keep some things relative. Thoughts on this?

Thanks much.

I know it is simply a matter of adding 'dist', but I am wanting gulp to handle that as a task.

Answer (score -1):

Change all the `../bower_components` and `ppt` to be `dist`.